# Convert Collection<String> to Collection<Object>

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a Collection of Strings which I want to iterate and do a DB query on each of them and collect the response of each query into a Collection of Objects. I am sure we can do this through a for loop iterator but is there a way to do it with Java8 Streams ? This is what I came up with -

```java
static Collection<Action> getActions(Collection<String> actionIds, RequestContext rc) {
    List<Collection<Action>> ac = actionIds.stream().map(str -> hashmap.get(str)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    return ac.get(0);
}
```

`Action` is a custom class. I read that I may need to do something like this - https://itsallbinary.com/java-8-create-custom-streams-collector/ .
Is this necessary ? Or any easier ways ?

If I use this `.collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new))`, it gives me `Collection<Collection<Action>>`

Comment: Nope. I need a Collection<Action>. And I cannot do new Collection<Action>();

Comment: If I use this .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new)) it gives me Collection<Collection<Action>>

Comment: Does `hashmap.get(str)` return a `Collection` of `Action`s (it seems so)?

Comment: @MarkusRatzer yes, it does. If I remove .collect() completely. It says required Collection<Action> but provided Stream<Object>

Comment: You _could_ use `...flatMap(str -> hashmap.get(str).stream()).collect(...)` (instead of `...map(...).collect(...)`), but that _might_ not be correct from a business logic point of view.
Alternatively `...map(str -> hashmap.get(str).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(...)` which is more readible to some people.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `hashmap` is a `Map<String, Collection<Action>>` which can be converted into filtered `Collection<Action>` using `Stream::flatMap`, as suggested in the comments.

Possibly it's worth to filter available actionIds as a defensive measure.  Also, some specific implementation of the collection needs to be selected or at least `Set` or `List` depending on the actual requirements (e.g. if the order of the actions needs to be maintained, or if the duplicate actions need to be filtered, etc.)

Most likely, a mere `Collectors::toList` would be fine for the result:

```java
static Collection<Action> getActions(Collection<String> actionIds, RequestContext rc) {
    return actionIds.stream()
        .filter(hashmap::containsKey) // make sure nulls not returned
        .map(hashmap::get) // Stream<Collection<Action>>
        .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<Action>
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<Action>
}
```

---

"Unique" values may be retrieved using `Stream::distinct` before collecting to list or by collecting to a set instead of list (using `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the order of insertion):

```java
static Collection<Action> getDistinctActions(Collection<String> actionIds, RequestContext rc) {
    return actionIds.stream()
        .filter(hashmap::containsKey) // make sure nulls not returned
        .flatMap(actions -> actions.stream()) // Stream<Action>
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```